# The arctangent of tangent x is not calculated precisely

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, trigonometry

I need tangent, arctangent functions for my Python program. I tried np.arctan and np.tan but observed a strange behaviour. In principle, the arctangent of tangent of some number is the number itself, but the code below doesn't give a precise value.

```
import numpy as np
x = 10
print(np.arctan(np.tan(x)))
```

When I change x to 2*x or 3*x, then the result is even more inaccurate. 
I tried math.tan, math.atan but the result was the same.

Can someone please explain why it happens(which of the two functions is wrong), and under which condition one should be careful about using the arctangent and tangent functions?

Answer (score 5):

three things to note:

1. in python (as in all programming languages i have ever looked at) trigonometric functions work with angles in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) i.e. the range `[0, 2*pi)` represents the 'full circle'
2. `tan` is periodic: `tan(x) = tan(pi + x)` (again note that this is in radians; in python `tan(x) = tan(180 + x)` will not be true!).
3. [`arctan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan.html?numpy.arctan) returns a value in `[-pi/2, pi/2)`.

in your example you fall back on the *correct* result in `[-pi/2, pi/2)`:

```
import numpy as np

x = 10
print(np.arctan(np.tan(x)))  # 0.575222039231
print(10 % (np.pi / 2))      # 0.5752220392306207
```

your function `np.arctan(np.tan(x))` is equivalent to (the computationally less expensive)

```
def arctan_tan(x):
    ret = x % np.pi
    if ret > np.pi / 2:
        ret -= np.pi
    return ret
```

Comment: `math.remainder(x, math.pi)` is a nice way of spelling the `arctan_tan` function, but it's only available in Python >= 3.7, and there's no NumPy equivalent yet (but see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/9963).

Comment: @MarkDickinson what is the difference between `math.remainder(x, pi)` and `x % pi` then? (`np.remainder` will broadcast, i assume).

Comment: Assuming `y` is positive, `math.remainder(x, y)` reduces to the interval `[-y/2, y/2]`, instead of to `[0, y]`. It's the remainder operation specified in IEEE 754 (and in the C standards). It has the nice property that for IEEE 754 arithmetic, the result is always exactly computed, with no rounding error. (That last part is also true for `x % y` when `x` is positive, but not necessarily for negative `x`.)